# What is the AXReplaceRangeWithText macOS accessibility attribute?

Tags: macos, user-interface, accessibility-api

In macOS Mojave 10.14, a new AXReplaceRangeWithText attribute appears in the result when calling the AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames() function on the UI element under the mouse for many applications. But when I call the AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue() function on the UI element and pass the AXReplaceRangeWithText attribute, it either causes the target application to crash or, if it's a text field or text area, enters garbage text in the target application.

Can anybody explain what the AXReplaceRangeWithText attribute is, how to use it, what it does, and who is responsible for it? It is not documented by Apple and it does not appear in the accessibility API header files. I filed a bug report with Apple and saw no action.